# using a c++ function in c#

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

i have a function defined in c++, and i want to include it in some c# gui.
This is what i've done:

in cpp file:

```
extern "C"             //No name mangling
__declspec(dllexport)  //Tells the compiler to export the function
int                    //Function return type     
__cdecl                //Specifies calling convention, cdelc is default, 
                   //so this can be omitted 
test(int number){
    return number + 1;
}
```

in cs file:

```
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = test(9);
        }
    }

    public static class NativeTest
    {
        private const string DllFilePath = @"c:\test.dll";
        [DllImport(DllFilePath , CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern int test(int a);

    }
}
```

and i get this error:

> Error 1   The name 'test' does not exist in the current context   Line 28

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with the interop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `NativeTest.test()` rather than just `test()`.

Comment: and mark `test` method's access modifier elevated(internal or public or what ever)

Comment: @richiehindie Please explain why.

Comment: Thanks! Using that and folding the functions with "unsafe" it worked like charm

Comment: @Sorin: Because the `test` function is a member of the `NativeTest` class, and hence lives within that class's namespace.  As @chris points out in his comment on the question, this isn't anything to do with interop.